# How to update state of react native app based on time interval

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i am new to react native , wanted to understand how i could improve the logic/code ?

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (orderbookLastJsonMessage){
          setOrderbookData(parseOrderbookResponse(orderbookLastJsonMessage));
    }

    return () => {
      setOrderbookData(undefined);
    }

  }, [orderbookLastJsonMessage]);
```

I receive `orderbookLastJsonMessage` data `4-5 times within a seconds` and it makes my UI/UX slow, i want to slowdown the rendering.

I want to reject/discard last 3 data received and accept/process the latest one instead of processing/rendering 4times, i would like to render/process only once per second.

I have tried `setTimeOut()` but seems not a good approach.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a date snapshot every time you record `orderbookLastJsonMessage` in your state.

Every time you update your `orderbookLastJsonMessage`, you can get the current date and compare it to the picture when you find out if it's been 1 second.

Alternatively, you can make a counter, for example, from 0 to 4, and on each update `orderbookLastJsonMessage` add to it 1.

When the counter reaches 4, then you zero it to 0 and write the `orderbookLastJsonMessage` into your state.